# Whats wrong with the difference tool QGIS 2.14.1?

Tags: qgis, differences, qgis-2.14

I want to get the difference between two poligons. 
[image: Ejemplo de lo que quiero obtener]

I compare the result from Arcgis erase tool and QGIS difference. ArcGIS give me that I want, but Qgis don't.

Why?
[image: Results]

QGIS not only give wrong results,don't give me the holes that I want to fill.

Anyone knows why this don't works?.
I don't have selected polygons in QGIS.

Comment: Can you provide test data? Are any of the input geometries invalid? This should probably be a bug report rather than a GIS.SE question.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer.  I get the same result in ArcGIS and QGIS, but in QGIS I used the difference tool from SAGA vector polygon tools.

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution! Would still be great if you could file a ticket for the difference tool that didn't work.

Comment: ¿How can I get the invalid geometries?

Comment: You can check validity using Vector | Geometry tools | Check validity

Comment: I checked the invalid geometries and have 1845 errors, in the polygon with holes. I think that it happened when I covert from raster to vector. But why the SAGA tool did the process and the QGIS difference didn't? and how can I fix all the invalid geometries? (for a next time)

Comment: Probably related to http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14504. You could try the PostGIS Geoprocessing tools plugin for Processing "Fix invalid polygons"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same result in ArcGIS and QGIS, but in QGIS I used the difference tool from SAGA vector polygon tools.

Here the result.[image: Result]

Comment: I have had some issues with the QGIS difference tool for larger complex datasets. But SAGA has worked well.