# Saga difference vector tool

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, saga, differences

My QGis Difference tool doesn't work really well, it gives me lots of little squigly lines. i read in the link below there is such a thing as a vector diffence tool from SAGA, but i can't find it.

[Whats wrong with the difference tool QGIS 2.14.1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187816/whats-wrong-with-the-difference-tool-qgis-2-14-1/187819?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Does anyone know where i can find the SAGA vector difference tool, or other ways to calculate the difference between 2 polygons?

i'm using QGis 2.6.0

Comment: SAGA tools can be found in the processing toolbox.

Comment: If you want help troubleshooting the QGIS Difference tool, please add screenshots of the settings you used, the input layers, and the output layer.